# rsyslog $programname dynamic split

Tags: config, rsyslog

I would like to set up an rsyslog to log into a database. The program name would have a specific structure:

something.{hostname}.{dbname}.{table}

Is there any opportunity to split this into variables that I can use later? I mean I need to know the table name when I specify the INSERT.

So my question is how can I do that? This is what I have so far :) :

```
# Only if we sent the log
if ($syslogfacility-text == 'local7' and $programname startswith 'something.') then {
    #############
    # Templates #
    #############

    # I need something like this but with variables
    # $template gw1,"insert into gateway (Message, Facility, FromHost, Priority, DeviceReportedTime, ReceivedAt, InfoUnitID, SysLogTag) values (\'%msg%\', %syslogfacility%, \'%HOSTNAME%\', %syslogpriority%, \'%timereported:::date-mysql%\', \'%timegenerated:::date-mysql%\', %iut%, \'%syslogtag%\')",SQL

    # *.* :ommysql:127.0.0.1,Syslog,rsyslog,passwordhere;gw1
}
```

And an other question is if the above is done then how can I split the $msg into a dynamic SQL? I mean if I don't want to specify the column names in the SQL script, only the values. The number of values could be different in different logs.

Thank you for your help!